# OAuth custom provider c#

Tags: oauth-2.0

I need to create a my own OAUTH Provider, to validate third party application requests, i do not want to use Google, Twitter, LinkedIn, Microsoft providers. I have to create my own provider to authenticate request and return an access token to the client. But all the help on the net is related to external providers(Google, LinkedIn,Twitter, Facebook..). Can anyone help me achieve in creating my own custom Provider?

Comment: I researched this a while back, and it turned out to be a bad idea because there are endless security concerns to be aware of, and endless updates keeping ahead of hackers.  In the end, most people opted for the free ThinkTecture server.  The guys behind it are serious leaders in the technology. http://www.thinktecture.com/identityAndAccessControl

Comment: Have you read the spec for [OAuth 1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849) or [OAuth 2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749)?

Comment: I need to use OAUTH 2.0, as per my client's requirement to achieve the same.

Comment: Basically, I need to authenticate the third party user's, if there is anything else available other than OAUTH, then I am OK with following that also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Roland said if you get through the spec it pretty straight forward.

At a high level this is what you will need to do to support AuthCode grant pattern :

Assuming:
Your application own the users.

- Issue clientid/secrets to each of the 3rd Party applications.
- On your server create end points for

  - authorize
  - token

When the client hits the authorize end point like below:

`/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<clientID>&state=xyz&redirect_uri=http://thirdparty.com`

- Redirect the client to a login page.
- Validate the username/pwd provided by the user.
- If successful, call the 3rd Party clients redirect URI with authCode.
- If failure, call the 3rd Party clients redirect URI with error(pre-published).

Sample callback here
`https://thirdparty.com/cb?code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA&state=xyz`

Client will then call on the /token URI with authcode with something like below:

```
/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=SplxlOBeZQQYbYS6WxSbIA&redirect_uri=http://thirdparty.com
```

Generate a token, store it against the clientID, UserId and respond back with the token.
Something like below

```
{
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA",
   "example_parameter":"example_value"
 }
```

When the 3rd party access your services/resources validate the token against the client and userid and grant or deny access.

This is to get started but there can be a lot more customization that you can do with scope and other OAuth2 patterns.

Comment: When is the client secret involved ?